# Convert Item to Map<String, AttributeValue> for DynamoDB in Java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Is there any Java API for DynamoDB to convert from `Item` to `Map<String, AttributeValue>` without implementing it on my own?

**EDIT**

`item.asMap()` will return `Map<String, Object>`, not `Map<String, AttributeValue>`. Just wondering is there any direct API for this?

Comment: [Item#asMap](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Item.html#asMap--)? [Item#attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Item.html#attributes--)? Or do they not do what you want

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, but I've managed to find it:

```
// Item item
InternalUtils.toAttributeValues(item)
```

However, above API is deprecated in newer DynamoDB library which basically delegates the call to `ItemUtils` which is not deprecated fortunately. So I ended up using this:

```
ItemUtils.toAttributeValues(item)
```

Hope this will help others in future!

Comment: Javadoc, in case you’re interested, is here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/ItemUtils.html

Comment: yeah, Now I've took look for `ItemUtils` and found it has a decent collections of utility functions. I don't know why I didn't find it in usual way. Thanks!

Comment: This method is not implemented in Java SDK 2.x Please update your answer.

Comment: I found the `ItemUtils` class in `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document`.  So just add: `import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.*;`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the method [`asMap`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Item.html#asMap--):

> Returns all attributes of the current item as a map.

---

Updated answer:

To get a `Map<String, AttributeValue>` you can use [`ItemUtils.toAttributeValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/ItemUtils.html):

> Converts an Item into the low-level representation; or null if the input is null.

as follow

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> map = ItemUtils.toAttributeValue(item);
```

Comment: @Kaidul I updated the answer taking in consideration you updated question.

Comment: This method is not implemented in Java SDK 2.x. Please update your answer.

Comment: @dudi the question was answered at the end of 2018 when the sdk 2 was an early version (it was realeased 1 week before the answer if I remember well). If you need an answer for version 2 instead of downvoting ask a new question and wait for somebody to answer it.

Comment: I figured out, that the manual mapping in Java SDK 2 is not really necessary when you are using enhanced DynamoDB client with DynamoDB mapper annotations. Please check this https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/developer/introducing-enhanced-dynamodb-client-in-the-aws-sdk-for-java-v2/ out for more information.